# how to get services account credentials(bigquery)

Tags: google-bigquery

**Problem: ** When a new user(say USER B) is created with certain roles(i.e bigquery user and bigquery data viewer) from owner account(SAY USER A) I`m not able to get the service account credentials(from USER B) in order to use that credentials to access the projects from python.
This user should not have admin/editor role.

Tried giving bigquery user wasnt able to get the credentials. Is there any other roles need to be given.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is your question about how to access biquery from python using a service account ?

Comment: @kiranmathew yes but when this  service account credentials is shared to new user, the new user should not have permission to edit any projects, datasets, etc.

Comment: @ben Based on my understanding,you can consider giving  ‘Bigquery Job user’ role and  [Bigquery Data Viewer](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#bigquery.dataViewer) role. For more information you can follow this [article](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#bq-permissions).You can also give specific permissions for [datasets](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/control-access-to-resources-iam#view_the_access_policy_of_a_resource).If my answer addressed your question please consider accepting else let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the BigQuery API, you must first authenticate to verify your client's identity.You can use a service account for authentication.There are two ways to authenticate:

1: [Authenticating with Application Default Credentials](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authentication/getting-started).

Application Default Credentials let your application use service account credentials to access BigQuery resources as its own identity.

2: [Authenticating with a service account key file](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authentication/service-account-file).

Manually create and obtain service account credentials to use BigQuery when an application is deployed on premises or to other public clouds. You can set the environment variable to load the credentials using Application Default Credentials, or you can specify the path to load the credentials manually in your application code.

You can refer to the below sample code where  I have authenticated with a service account key file.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
import os

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS']='/home/demo.json'
def query_stackoverflow():
   client = bigquery.Client()
   query_job = client.query(
       """
       SELECT
         *
       FROM `bigquery-public-data.census_utility.fips_codes_all`


       LIMIT 10"""
   )


   results = query_job.result()  # Waits for job to complete.


   for row in results:
           print("{} : {} :{}".format(row.summary_level, row.summary_level_name,row.county_fips_code))


query_stackoverflow()
```

I run the above code with the service account that has the  `BigQuery Job User` role.For more information on appropriate roles and permissions, you can follow this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#bq-permissions).